# Is there a way to introduce a temporary wildcard in Snakemake from a list?

Tags: python, bash, snakemake

I recently started using Snakemake. I am building a pipeline where the goal is to separate fractions of reads (based on their taxID by classification by Kraken2). I am having problems understanding how I may introduce a new wildcard based on a list of taxIDs.

I have:

1. A list of taxIDs that I want to examine further.
2. A script to extract reads from my original .fastq file based on taxID and the Kraken2 classification

The code displayed below is a subset of the pipeline but captures the problem.
The R-script extract_microbial_taxids.R generates a file with each taxID in a separate line.
The function SplitGenusList() splits this file into an array with each element being a taxID.

I would like to split an input .fastq-file and introduce taxID as a new wildcard - likely based on the taxID list from the R-script. Any clues as to how I may achieve this? The wildcard will then be used for a couple of rules, before only the {sample} wildcard is relevant again.

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("data/microbial_taxids/{sample}/genus_list.txt", sample = config["SAMPLE"])

rule extract_microbial_taxids:
    input:
        "data/kraken2_classification/{sample}/{sample}.report",
        config["Rlibpath"]
    output:
        "data/microbial_taxids/{sample}/genus_list.txt"
    script:
        "code/extract_microbial_taxids.R"

    
def SplitGenusList(genus_list):
        genus_list = open(genus_list)
        contents = genus_list.read()
        contents_split = contents.splitlines()
        return contents_split    
    
rule extract_microbial_reads:
        input:
            taxID_list = "data/microbial_taxids/{sample}/genus_list.txt",
            kraken_file = "data/kraken2_classification/{sample}/{sample}.kraken",
            reads = config["reads"]+"{sample}.fastq"
        output:
            taxID_reads = expand("data/microbial_reads/{sample}/{taxID}.fastq", taxID = SplitGenusList(input.taxID_list))
        shell:
            """
            for taxID in genus_list
            do
            python code/extract_kraken_reads.py --kraken {input.kraken_file} -s {input.reads} -o "data/microbial_reads/{sample}/$taxID\_.fastq" -t $taxID --include-children
            done
            """
```

**UPDATE**

After a lot of help from @Oliver and @dariober, I managed to construct a workflow that does as intended. I learned a few things from this:

1: Rule variables (such as `{input.taxID_list}`) should be written differently for python, `input.taxID_list`, and shell `{input.taxID_list}`.

2: the run command allows to combine python and shell (with the `shell()`function suggested by @dariober) in a way that seems very handy.

Here is the working code:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("data/microbial_taxids/{sample}/genus_list.txt", sample = config["SAMPLE"]),
     expand("data/microbial_reads/{sample}/extracting_microbial_reads.done", sample = config["SAMPLE"])


rule extract_microbial_taxids:
    input:
        "data/kraken2_classification/{sample}/{sample}.report",
        config["Rlibpath"]
    output:
        "data/microbial_taxids/{sample}/genus_list.txt"
    script:
        "code/extract_microbial_taxids.R"

def SplitGenusList(genus_list):
    genus_list = open(genus_list)
    contents = genus_list.read()
    contents_split = contents.splitlines()
    return contents_split

rule extract_microbial_reads:
    input:
        taxID_list="data/microbial_taxids/{sample}/genus_list.txt",
        kraken_file="data/kraken2_classification/{sample}/{sample}.kraken",
        reads=config["reads"] + "{sample}.fastq",
        report_file="data/kraken2_classification/{sample}/{sample}.report"
    output:
        touch("data/microbial_reads/{sample}/extracting_microbial_reads.done")
    run:
        import os
        genus_list = SplitGenusList(input.taxID_list)
        for taxID in genus_list:
            shell('python code/extract_kraken_reads.py -k {input.kraken_file} -s {input.reads} -o "data/microbial_reads/{wildcards.sample}/' + taxID + '_.fastq" -t ' + taxID + ' -r {input.report_file} --include-children')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understood you correctly, but essentially your just looking for a way to reference in your rule the variable `genus_list`, which is supposed to hold the taxIDs or interest, right?

Well, I think one major problem is here, that Snakemake needs to be able to derive concrete outputs in order to create the DAG, since it determines the order of rule executions. So even though you place `taxID_reads = expand(...)` in the output, still Snakemake will try to figure out the actual results for that. Hence, the function `SplitGenusList` is called, where then an error is produced due to non-existence of the file `genus_list`.

Thus, I would propose not to call this function in the input or output, but simply in the code block. In order to document a successful execution of the given rule, you can simply create a dummy-file.

**My suggestion:**

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("data/microbial_reads/{sample}/extracting_microbial_reads.done", sample=config["SAMPLE"])

rule extract_microbial_taxids:
    input:
        "data/kraken2_classification/{sample}/{sample}.report",
        config["Rlibpath"]
    output:
        "data/microbial_taxids/{sample}/genus_list.txt"
    script:
        "code/extract_microbial_taxids.R"


def SplitGenusList(genus_list):
    genus_list = open(genus_list)
    contents = genus_list.read()
    contents_split = contents.splitlines()
    return contents_split


rule extract_microbial_reads:
    input:
        taxID_list="data/microbial_taxids/{sample}/genus_list.txt",
        kraken_file="data/kraken2_classification/{sample}/{sample}.kraken",
        reads=config["reads"] + "{sample}.fastq"
    output:
        touch("data/microbial_reads/{sample}/extracting_microbial_reads.done")
    run:
        import os
        genus_list = SplitGenusList("data/microbial_taxids/" + wildcards.sample + "/genus_list.txt")
        for taxID in genus_list:
            os.system('python code/extract_kraken_reads.py --kraken ' + input.kraken_file + ' -s ' + input.reads +
                      ' -o "data/microbial_reads/' + wildcards.sample + '/' + taxID + '_.fastq" ' +
                      '-t ' + taxID + ' --include-children')
```

Comment: `Error in rule extract_microbial_reads:
    jobid: 0
    output: data/microbial_reads/reads_50/extracting_microbial_reads.done

RuleException:
FileNotFoundError in line 65 of /user_data/men/sepseq/clinical_studies/init_tests/kraken2_filter/Snakefile:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/microbial_taxids/{wildcards.sample}/genus_list.txt'`

Comment: Dear @Oliver Küchler, thanks a lot for your help and suggestion! It makes sense what you explain to me. I have an error when implementing the script, and I think it is related to, that the {sample} wildcard is not recognized as a wildcard in the script.

Comment: Yes, it seems like the parentheses around the wildcards in the code block were unneccesary. I removed them and updated my answer.

Comment: Also I updated the `rule all` to include the expansion of the results with `{sample}`

Comment: (+1) A couple of thoughts: Use `shell` (shell function, not shell block) instead of `os.system` to execute a system command in a `run` block; shouldn't the rule `all` be on top?; A more sophisticated solution would be to use [checkpoints](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution)

Comment: @dariober Thanks for the feedback. I moved the all-rule to the top now.
And indeed, the checkpoints look very interesting. I will take a closer look into that. Thanks for the hint-outs :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I got it to work by combining your suggestions! I am curious about the checkpoints: if you have the time I would be eager to know the idea of how to use it in this context.